# Flash AS2 how to stop character moving off screen + movement & rotation code

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Hey folks below is my code for moving my character player_mc it works fine he moves around the screen perfectly but I can't work out a away to stop him from walking off the screen. As I understand it if playermc =  x> stage width decrease by 5 increase by 5 etc and the same with y but why is this not working for me? Could you folks advise me on what I am doing wrong here? You can see the code marked as not working as a comment. 
Thanks   if you want to see the full code here's a link to another question I asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764305/educational-simulation-actionscript-2

```
   function rotatePlayer()
    {
        //calculate player_mc rotation, based on player position & mouse position 
        player_mc._rotation = Math.atan2(_ymouse - player_mc._y, _xmouse - player_mc._x) * radians2;

        // not working code: stage collision.
    if (player_mc._x > stage.width)
    {
        player_mc._x+50
    }
    if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT))
    {
    player_mc._x += 5; 
    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT))
    {
    player_mc._x -= 5;
    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.UP))
    {
    player_mc._y -= 5;
    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN))
    {
    player_mc._y += 5;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you new to AS2? If so, is there a reason you're not diving straight into AS3?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
if (player_mc._x > stage.width)
        {
            player_mc._x = stage.width
        }
if (player_mc._x < 0) {
    player_mc._x = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in AS2, you need to capitalize "Stage", so it needs to read something like

```
if (player_mc._x > Stage.width) {
    player_mc._x= Stage.width;
}
else if (player_mc._x < 0) {
    player_mc._x = 0;
}

if (player_mc._y > Stage.height) {
    player_mc._y= Stage.height;
}
else if (player_mc._y < 0) {
    player_mc._y = 0;
}
```

Place this code below the Key.isDown section, not above, otherwise there's a strange bounce back effect resulting from correcting the overshoot before another increment is added. Finally, you might want to subtract/add half the width of your player mc to the bounds so that half of it doesn't disappear.